# Как сделать перетаскивание фотографий на сайте ВК на рабочий стол?

Tags: javascript, вконтакте, google-chrome

Здравствуйте. Мне нужно через пользовательский скрипт сделать возможным перетаскивать зажатием мышки картинку **на компьютер**. Некоторые изображения на сайте поддерживают эту функцию, но не изображения в фотографиях.

Я уже искал в интернете решение этого вопроса, но постоянно попадалась реализация перетаскивания изображений именно по сайту, мне нужно не это.

По сути функция перетаскивания картинок должна работать по умолчанию, единственное, к чему мне получилось прийти, что, возможно, в ВК эту функцию блокирует какой-то скрипт. Что делать дальше я уже не знаю.

Comment: Вы можете перетащить только `img`. Вконтакте все фотографии обвернуты в несколько `div`-ов + `a`.

Comment: Это возможно исправить через простой скрипт, чтобы при этом сохранить функциональность сайта?

Comment: Исправить скриптом - в принципе можно, простым скриптом - сомневаюсь

Answer (score 0):

В общем, свою проблему получилось решить вот таким кривым образом,

```
setInterval( function() {
    if(document.domain === "vk.com") {
    try {
            if(document.getElementsByClassName("_buttonfwk")[0] === undefined) {
            _likespan = document.querySelectorAll('.pv_bottom_info.clear_fix')[0];
            _buttonfwk = document.createElement('a');
            _buttonfwk.className = "_buttonfwk";
            bfwk = "5";
            _likespan.insertBefore(_buttonfwk, _likespan.firstChild);
            }
        if(bfwk === "5") { _buttonfwk.innerHTML = "Включить перетаскивание"; }
        else { _buttonfwk.innerHTML = "Выключить перетаскивание"; }
        _buttonfwk.onclick=function(){
        if(bfwk === "5") { bfwk = "0" } 
        else { 
        bfwk = "5"; 
        window.location.reload(); }
        };
    } catch(err) {}
    }   
}, 1000);

setInterval( function() {
    if(document.domain === "vk.com") {
    try {
        if(document.querySelectorAll('.no_select.pv_image_wrap')[0] !== undefined) {
            if(bfwk !== "5") {
            document.querySelectorAll('.no_select.pv_image_wrap')[0].innerHTML = document.querySelectorAll('.no_select.pv_image_wrap')[0].innerHTML.replace('<div class="pv_img_area_wrap pv_init_hover" onmouseleave="return Photoview.onImageWrapMouseLeave(event)" onmousedown="return Photoview.onImageWrapMouseDown(event)" onmousemove="Photoview.onImageWrapMouseMove(event)" data-sf-skip="1">', '');

            document.querySelectorAll('.no_select.pv_image_wrap')[0].innerHTML = document.querySelectorAll('.no_select.pv_image_wrap')[0].innerHTML.replace('<div class="pv_img_area_wrap" onmouseleave="return Photoview.onImageWrapMouseLeave(event)" onmousedown="return Photoview.onImageWrapMouseDown(event)" onmousemove="Photoview.onImageWrapMouseMove(event)" data-sf-skip="1">', '');
            }
        }
    } catch(err) {}
    }
}, 1000);
```

Но, есть неудобство с выключением этой функции, ничего, кроме как использовать `window.location.reload();` мне в голову не пришло, если кому не сложно, предложите способ, который будет работать удобнее.

Comment: если нужен только первый то вместо `querySelectorAll(...)[0]` проще использовать `querySelector(...)`