# Как обновить конкретный элемент?

Tags: javascript, jquery, вконтакте, google-chrome

Этот вопрос связан с проблемой, которая появилась по ходу работы над [этим скриптом](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/769752/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B5-%D0%92%D0%9A-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BB), есть необходимость обновить элемент `document.querySelector('.no_select.pv_image_wrap')` на сайте ВК , чтобы сбросить все изменения, сделанные js скриптом, без необходимости полной перезагрузки страницы. Не подскажете, самим кодом или подробным объяснением того, как это сделать? Гугл привёл к jQuery, но хотелось бы найти способ без подключения его библиотек. Если иного нет, то объясните, как для недалёкого, каким образом обновлять конкретный элемент?